# Set width equal to hight

Tags: html, css, height, width, border

I'd like to create these boxes. The image whitch is by default in the middle should go on top while hover. As they do. But I'd like to have a "Border" around the image whitch was used to darken the box while no hover.

Does anyone have an idea how I can create this "Border"? I haven't found any solution how to set the img-containers width equal to it's height.

As an example on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFai8qTKvEM), but they used a font, i'd like to use a custom image.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #171717;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box .headline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box .headline .img-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box .headline .img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 80%;
  padding: 10%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover .headline {
  height: 33%;
 }
 
.box:hover .headline .img-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

 
 .box:hover .headline .img-container img {
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 
 .box .content {
   opacity: 0;
   padding: 5px;
   max-height: calc(66% - 10px);
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 }
 
.box:hover .content {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(255, 131, 96);">
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(125, 206, 130)">
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(232, 226, 136)">
  <div class="headline">
        <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(0,255,245)">
  <div class="headline">
        <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So are you saying you want your darkened borders when hovering to be circular instead of ovular like they are now?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It sould be circular

Comment: I would use a box-shadow to avoid playing with border-size here is the idea  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZEGKKgL

Comment: Yes this is a nice solution. Can i use relative units for the box-shadow or isn't that possible?

Comment: css variable can be used, so it can be used too for the box size and you do not need to mind about after.. %  won't work, it has no reference to be calculated . pen updated with css var  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZEGKKgL resize your box via the CSS variables.

Comment: I thik this is the best answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help from [@g-cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus) i've created my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #171717;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box .headline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box .headline .img-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box .headline .img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 80%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover .headline {
  height: 33%;
 }
 
.box:hover .headline .img-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: calc(200px * 0.33);/* Height of box multiplied with height of headline (Percentage) */ 
  margin-top: 2%;
}

 
 .box:hover .headline .img-container img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 
 .box .content {
   opacity: 0;
   padding: 5px;
   max-height: calc(66% - 10px);
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 }
 
.box:hover .content {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(255, 131, 96);">
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(125, 206, 130)">
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(232, 226, 136)">
  <div class="headline">
        <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(0,255,245)">
  <div class="headline">
        <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a width to your hover.  I think your issue is your container is bigger than the actual view box, so 50% is larger than you think.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #171717;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box .headline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box .headline .img-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box .headline .img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 80%;
  padding: 10%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover .headline {
  height: 33%;
 }
 
.box:hover .headline .img-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  width: 22.5%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

 
 .box:hover .headline .img-container img {
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 
 .box .content {
   opacity: 0;
   padding: 5px;
   max-height: calc(66% - 10px);
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 }
 
.box:hover .content {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(255, 131, 96);">
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(125, 206, 130)">
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(232, 226, 136)">
  <div class="headline">
        <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-color: rgb(0,255,245)">
  <div class="headline">
        <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1041/1041820.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
    Lorem ipsum<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've already had that but if I change the width or hight of the box the circle will become ovular

Comment: If you want to change the size of the box you can just change the size of the shadow to.